find duplicate more than x times in 3 dimensional list
I have a complex list which looks like this:
[name1,(valA, valB)], where name1 has no duplicate at all (it is a sequence of unique values) and the combination of (valA, valB) may be repeated, with the same name or with other names.
So for example:
[[john,(10.5, 8.2)],[nick,(7.2, 8.2)],[rog,(7.2, 8.2)],[rog,(8.5, 9.9)], [john,(12.0, 9.2)], [john,(7.2, 8.2)],[nick,(12.0, 9.2)]

The list is quite complex and it is some thousands entrys long.
In the first instance, I would like to know if there is (valA,ValB) which is repeated for more names. In the above example the value (7.2, 8.2) is repeated for nick, rog and john, while the value (12.0,9.2) is repeated in john and nick.
Then I would like to know if there are at least x (valA,valB) which are repeated for at least 3 names, so -in a huge list- i can seach for 50 values (valA,valB) which are repeated for at least 3 names of the list.
I know it is quite complex but I don't know how else to explain it...
I found a way -with itertools- to work with simple list of values and grab values which are repeated at least 5 (in the example) times, as for the example below
from itertools import groupby
   list_after = []
   for k, group in groupby(only_AB):
      lst = list(group)
      if len(lst)  >= 5:
         list_after.append(k)
      

The problem is that I don't know how to add the 3rd dimension (the name in my example).
How can I do it?
Any help is appreciated

Do you need the (valA,ValB) that appear in the list at least x times? Or do you also need their names?

"if there are at least x (valA,valB) which are repeated for at least 3 names": do you mean for 3 unique names, or can the 3 names be the same name?

Then I would like to know if there are at least x (valA,valB)... does it mean that you just want True or False or you need to extract pairs?

Be aware that floating point values may or may not compare equal (depends a bit on how the values were obtained), because of floating point precision issues.

"where name1 has no duplicate ... the combination of (valA, valB) may be repeated, with the same name ...": this sounds like a contradiction. If the name part has no duplicate, how can there be the same name?

have you tried using a dictionary for the data ?

look into defaultdict in python

@JeremiahHerberg I will need also names

@9769953 yes, unique names

@MilosStojanovic I would need pairs, not only True/False

@9769953 I don't mind working with them as string, not floating if that helps

@trincot you are right, I mean the combination name,(valA,valB) is always unique

If you use Decimal instead of float when creating the values (or reading them in), then there's a better guarantee for equality when comparing the values.

Here is an approach using pandas. I've rounded your values to one decimal place to minimise the chance of error in floating point comparison.
The necessity of rounding will depend on the source of your data. You risk errors when using groupby() with floating points. As that link sets out, in Python (and most other languages)  0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 == 0.3 is False. However, round(0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1, 1) == round(0.3, 1) is True. You may not need to worry about this in this instance - it will depend how the original values in your list were created.
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [(name, round(valA, 1), round(valB, 1)) for name, (valA, valB) in data],
    columns= ["name", "valA", "valB"]
)

grouped = (
    df
    .groupby(['valA', 'valB'])['name']
    .agg(['unique', 'nunique'])
    .reset_index()
)

print(grouped)

This returns:
   valA  valB             unique  nunique
0   7.2   8.2  [nick, rog, john]        3
1   8.5   9.9              [rog]        1
2  10.5   8.2             [john]        1
3  12.0   9.2       [john, nick]        2

You can filter this for any length, e.g.:
print(grouped[grouped["nunique"] >= 3])

This produces:
   valA  valB             unique  nunique
0   7.2   8.2  [nick, rog, john]        3


For larger Data this is good approach , round(valA, 1), round(valB, 1) .  this is rounding value to one decimal point, if its requirement then using this is fine

If your data is too big consider chunk processing or use something like Dask

@SamR Thanks a lot, but I cannot round them... or at least not with 1 decimal (perhaps 6 or 7, based on my values)

@gianluca, but that is not a problem, right? I suppose you can change that 1 to your liking? It isn't relevant to the answer in my opinion.

@trincot sure, but I referred at Sasanka comment about large data and rounding. So yes, the proposed solution works well for me. I will convert it to the real data I have and let you all know in case I have still questions. Thanks a lot!!!

@gianluca If you don't want round up then also you can replace it with [(name, valA, valB) for name, (valA, valB) in data],

@gianluca I've edited the answer to explain the rounding. It's not necessary in this case - I don't know if it's necessary in your real data, it depends. It's also not the only approach to this issue. But doing floating point comparison and expecting it to always work is not a great idea.

using numpy.isclose might help with a unique identifier for each pair based on tolerance level

With
data = [
    ["john", (10.5, 8.2)], ["nick", (7.2, 8.2)], ["rog", (7.2, 8.2)], ["rog", (8.5, 9.9)], ["john", (12.0, 9.2)], ["john", (7.2, 8.2)], ["nick", (12.0, 9.2)]
]

you could just collect the names (in lists) in a dictionary that uses the value tuples as keys
repeated = {}
for name, vals in data:
    repeated.setdefault(vals, []).append(name)
selection = {vals: names for vals, names in repeated.items() if len(names) >= 3}

to get
# repeated
{(7.2, 8.2): ['nick', 'rog', 'john'],
 (8.5, 9.9): ['rog'],
 (10.5, 8.2): ['john'],
 (12.0, 9.2): ['john', 'nick']}

# selection
{(7.2, 8.2): ['nick', 'rog', 'john']}

If the name-value pairs could contain duplicates and you want to avoid that in the counting, you could use sets instead of lists to collect the names (see comment by @9769953):
repeated = {}
for name, vals in data:
    repeated.setdefault(vals, set()).add(name)


What about using a set instead of a list to add the names to? That guarantees the set of names is unique. Given the reply to my question (see comments), this appears to be what the OP wants.

@9769953 Yes, that makes sense if there's a potential for name repetition.

I think it would be easier to use a dictionary :
data = [
    ['john', (10.5, 8.2)],
    ['nick', (7.2, 8.2)],
    ['rog', (7.2, 8.2)],
    ['rog', (8.5, 9.9)],
    ['john', (12.0, 9.2)],
    ['john', (7.2, 8.2)],
    ['nick', (12.0, 9.2)]
]

data_hist = { d[1] : 0 for d in data }

for d in data:
   data_hist[d[1]] += 1

"""
Transforms `data` list to the following dictionary :
{ 
    (10.5, 8.2) : len(['john']),
    ...
    (12.0, 9.2) : len(['john', 'nick'])
}
"""

Then you just have to filter this dictionary to get only the keys that repeat, for instance, 3 times or more.
MIN_REP = 3

output = { key : val for key, val in data_hist.items() if val >= MIN_REP }

"""
Here output is now equal to :
{
    (7.2, 8.2): 3
}
"""


You can use a default dictionary and a counter (both from the collections module) to count the number of val1,val2 pairs, and the names associated with them:
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

def find_common_values(data_list, min_occurrences):
    name_mapping = defaultdict(list)
    def round_tuple_values(t):
        return tuple(round(x, 2) for x in t)
    
    value_tuples = []
    for name, value_tuple in data_list:
        rounded_val_tuple = round_tuple_values(value_tuple)
        value_tuples.append(rounded_val_tuple)
        name_mapping[value_tuple].append(name)
    
    tuple_counts = Counter(value_tuples)
    
    common_values = [(tuple_, list(set(name_mapping[tuple_]))) 
                     for tuple_, count in tuple_counts.items() 
                     if count >= min_occurrences]

    
    return common_values

data = [
    ['john',(10.5, 8.2)],
    ['nick',(7.2, 8.2)],
    ['rog',(7.2, 8.2)],
    ['rog',(8.5, 9.9)], 
    ['john',(12.0, 9.2)], 
    ['john',(7.2, 8.2)],
    ['nick',(12.0, 9.2)]
]

print(find_common_values(data, 2,))

print(find_common_values(data, 3))

This will output:
[((7.2, 8.2), ['rog', 'john', 'nick']), ((12.0, 9.2), ['john', 'nick'])]
[((7.2, 8.2), ['rog', 'john', 'nick'])]


I am not sure if this will help you but try to
Organize the Data: Use a dictionary to map each (valA, valB) pair to a set of names that have that pair.
Filter Results: Find (valA, valB) pairs that appear under at least x different names

You can also use groupby from itertools:
lst = [['john', (10.5, 8.2)], ['nick', (7.2, 8.2)], ['rog', (7.2, 8.2)], ['rog', (8.5, 9.9)], ['john', (12.0, 9.2)], ['john', (7.2, 8.2)], ['nick', (12.0, 9.2)]]

from itertools import groupby
key = lambda x: (*x[1],)

res = {i:[k[0] for k in j] for i,j in groupby(sorted(lst, key = key), key = key)}
res
{(7.2, 8.2): ['nick', 'rog', 'john'], (8.5, 9.9): ['rog'], (10.5, 8.2): ['john'], (12.0, 9.2): ['john', 'nick']}


You could directly filter out:
{i:[k[0] for k in v] for i,j in groupby(sorted(lst, key = key), key = key) if len(v:=list(j))>=3}
{(7.2, 8.2): ['nick', 'rog', 'john']}


If using pandas:
pd.DataFrame(lst).groupby(1, as_index = False).agg(tuple)
             1                  0
0   (7.2, 8.2)  (nick, rog, john)
1   (8.5, 9.9)             (rog,)
2  (10.5, 8.2)            (john,)
3  (12.0, 9.2)       (john, nick)

pd.DataFrame(lst).groupby(1, as_index = False).agg(tuple).loc[lambda x: x.iloc[:,1].apply(len) >=3]
            1                  0
0  (7.2, 8.2)  (nick, rog, john)


"You can also use groupby from itertools" sounds odd, since they already did that. What's the advantage of (*x[1],) over just x[1]? If you do like that syntax, you could also do for i,[*v] in groupby instead of the walrus.
